# Output SVG as code instead of image tag in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, svg, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to upload images to my site.
After allowing SVG as filetype, I want to output the uploaded SVG image as "code". The template should output the `<svg>` tag with all the paths.

At the moment I'm using the following code to show the `<img>` tag:

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

I also tried to get the ID or use the URL to print out the `<svg>` tag. But it doesn't work. Any ideas how I could get the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working answer here https://code.mukto.info/html-img-tag-to-html-svg-tag-wordpress/, just applied it to my project - everything works like charm.

Also I copied the `jQuery` code below, just don't forget to set a class "SVG" for your IMG tag.

```js
/** Image to SVG **/
// chage img tag class to svg or other
$("img.svg").each(function () {
    var $img = $(this);
    var imgID = $img.attr("id");
    var imgClass = $img.attr("class");
    var imgURL = $img.attr("src");

    $.get(
        imgURL,
        function (data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = $(data).find("svg");

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if (typeof imgID !== "undefined") {
                $svg = $svg.attr("id", imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if (typeof imgClass !== "undefined") {
                $svg = $svg.attr("class", imgClass + " replaced-svg");
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr("xmlns:a");

            // Check if the viewport is set, else we gonna set it if we can.
            if (!$svg.attr("viewBox") && $svg.attr("height") && $svg.attr("width")) {
                $svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + $svg.attr("height") + " " + $svg.attr("width"));
            }

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);
        },
        "xml"
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By Using file_get_contents() function you can output an svg code from wordpress backend.

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('image');
$svgImage = $image['url'];

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <?php echo file_get_contents($svgImage);?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

if we you wanna output svg from files then it should be written as:

```
<?= file_get_contents( get_template_directory() . '/images/icons/dotted-line.svg' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

replace < by `&lt;` and > by `&gt;`

Comment: what do you mean with that?